# Nightly Branch Merging

Tags: github

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to setup my github repository with a script that would automatically merge certain branches each night. in our structure we have splits to facilitate us working on multiple projects on the same application simultaneously that will deploy at different date so currently each day i have to merge the branches for the branch that will go to production soonest into the branch that will go next and so on down to develop and was thinking this could probably be automated but wasn't sure how.

Comment: you can use schedule job https://github.com/marketplace/actions/schedule-job-action#define-scheduled-job

Answer (score 0):

Create a job
`.github-scheduled-workflows/merge.yml`

Use schedule as action

then use a merge branch action like https://github.com/bholland-bh/merge-branch

This will merge all branches matching `development*` regex

```
name: "example-cron-action"
on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 2 * * *'    # At 2am every day

jobs:
  merge:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Merge all development branches -> production
        uses: bholland-bh/merge-branch@master
        with:
          type: now
          from_branch: "development*"
          target_branch: production
          github_token: ${{ github.token }}
```